# Laravel5.2 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Tags: laravel, xampp, laravel-5

I am building a website with Laravel 5.2 and I did a form in layout blade:

```
<form action="POST"  action="{{url('subscribe')}}" class="searchform">
       {!! csrf_field() !!}
   <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address" name="email" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i></button>
<p>Get the most recent updates from <br />our site and be updated your self...</p>
    </form>
```

And this is my route

```
Route::post('/subscribe', 'Front@subscrib');
```

And this function in the controller Front

```
public function subscrib()
    {
        echo"we in subsc function";
       if (Request::isMethod('post')) {
            Subscribe::create([
                'email' => Request::get('email')

            ]);
       }

    }
```

But when I write email in the form, I get this error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 823
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
```

And URL go to

```
http://localhost/larashop/public/POST?_token=ALqduK9gW6Xdnq9iOJzyu7kMji1z3LCXDgeQehoO&email=azharnabil%40yahoo.com
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set your form's action - where it sends the data - to `POST` (the second `action` attribute is being ignored as a result).

You should be setting the **method** to `POST`.

```
<form action="POST"  action="{{url('subscribe')}}" class="searchform">
```

should be:

```
<form method="POST"  action="{{url('subscribe')}}" class="searchform">
```